# If else with three variables

Tags: javascript, if-statement

since two days I experiment with code.org in classroom and my pupils and I have written a small self-assessment mobile app for oral participation in class.

We defined three variables 'schulterklopfen', 'neutral' and 'warnung' which represent short comments that we would like to display in the final screen of the app according to the calculated final mark (variable 'note').

We intended to do this with if-else, but did not get it to work. So we tried three if-statements as shown in the code below and it also did not function.

The intended effect is as following:

`note <= 5.5 - setText("feedback", warnung);`
`note > 5.5 and <=6 - setText("feedback", neutral);`
`note > 6 - setText("feedback", schulterklopfen);`

I would be glad if someone can push me into the right direction!

```
var note = 0;
var schulterklopfen = "Auf die Schulter geklopft!";
var neutral = "Auf die Schulter geklopft!";
var warnung = "Ojo - piojo! Nimm die Beine in die Hand, mein Freund!";
setScreen("appstart");
playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
playSpeech("Genera to nota para participacion en la clase de Aleman hoy dia. Si no entiendes aleman, estas frito!", "female", "Español (LATAM)");
hideElement("startbutton");
hideElement("image6");
setTimeout(function() {
  showElement("startbutton");
  showElement("image6");
}, 5600);
onEvent("startbutton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("frage1");
  playSpeech("Bist du heute motiviert in die Deutschstunde gekommen?", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("jabock");
  hideElement("keinenbock");
  hideElement("image11");
  setTimeout(function() {
  showElement("jabock");
  showElement("keinenbock");
  showElement("image11");
  hideElement("deinenote");
  }, 3500);
});
onEvent("jabock", "click", function( ) {
  playSpeech("Das ist sehr gut! Das wirkt sich positiv auf deine Zensur aus! Aber wie aktiv hast du gesprochen, wie oft hast du auf Deutsch gesprochen?", "male", "Deutsch");
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  hideElement("aktivgesprochen");
  hideElement("tendenziellaktivgesprochen");
  hideElement("wenigeraktivgesprochen");
  hideElement("image5");
  hideElement("image4");
  note = note + 7;
  setScreen("sprechanteil");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("aktivgesprochen");
    showElement("tendenziellaktivgesprochen");
    showElement("wenigeraktivgesprochen");
    showElement("image5");
  showElement("image4");
  hideElement ("deinenote2");
  hideElement ("label8");
  }, 10300);
  setText("deinenote2", note);
});
onEvent("keinenbock", "click", function( ) {
    console.log("keinenbock clicked!");
    playSpeech("Das ist so schade! Mit nur ein wenig mehr Kraft könntest du so einfach eine Sieben kriegen! Aber sag mir mal: wie oft hast du heute aktiv Deutsch gesprochen?", "male", "Deutsch");
    playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
    hideElement("aktivgesprochen");
    hideElement("tendenziellaktivgesprochen");
    hideElement("wenigeraktivgesprochen");
    hideElement("image5");
     hideElement("image4");
    note = note + 5;
    setScreen("sprechanteil");
     setTimeout(function() {
       showElement("aktivgesprochen");
       showElement("tendenziellaktivgesprochen");
       showElement("wenigeraktivgesprochen");
       hideElement("label8");
       hideElement("deinenote2");
       showElement("image5");
       showElement("image4");
     }, 10300);
    setText("deinenote2", note);
});
onEvent("aktivgesprochen", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Respekt! Du bist doch definitiv auf dem richtigen Weg! Jetzt sag mir noch, wie oft du heute in der Stunde Spanisch gequatscht hast!", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("keinspanisch");
    hideElement("seltenspanisch");
    hideElement("oftspanisch");
  note = note + 7;
  note= note/2;
  setScreen("spanischesgequatsche");
  setTimeout(function() {
    hideElement("label8");
    hideElement("deinenote2");
    showElement("keinspanisch");
    showElement("seltenspanisch");
    showElement("oftspanisch");
    hideElement ("spanisch_gequatscht");
    hideElement ("label10");
  }, 10300);
  setText("spanisch_gequatscht", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("tendenziellaktivgesprochen", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Mach weiter so, aber ich will definitiv noch mehr von dir hören! Jetzt sag mir noch, wie oft du heute in der Stunde Spanisch gequatscht hast!", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("keinspanisch");
    hideElement("seltenspanisch");
    hideElement("oftspanisch");
  note = note + 5.7;
  note = note/2;
  setScreen("spanischesgequatsche");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("keinspanisch");
    showElement("seltenspanisch");
    showElement("oftspanisch");
    hideElement ("spanisch_gequatscht");
    hideElement ("label10");
  }, 10300);
  setText("spanisch_gequatscht", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("wenigeraktivgesprochen", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Besser als nichts, aber definitiv noch nicht genug! Jetzt sag mir noch, wie oft du heute in der Stunde Spanisch gequatscht hast!", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("keinspanisch");
    hideElement("seltenspanisch");
    hideElement("oftspanisch");
  note = note + 3.9;
  note = note/2;
  setScreen("spanischesgequatsche");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("keinspanisch");
    showElement("seltenspanisch");
    showElement("oftspanisch");
    hideElement ("spanisch_gequatscht");
    hideElement ("label10");
  }, 10300);
  setText("spanisch_gequatscht", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("keinspanisch", "click", function( ) {
  stopSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3");
  playSpeech("Du bist ein Held! Und wie sieht es mit dem Handy aus? Hast du das unter Kontrolle während der Deutschstunde?", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("handykeinproblem");
    hideElement("handynochproblem");
    hideElement("handyproblem");
    note = note + 7;
    note = note/2;
    setScreen("handy");
    setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("handykeinproblem");
    showElement("handynochproblem");
    showElement("handyproblem");
     hideElement ("label9");
    hideElement ("note_3");
  }, 10300);
    setText("note_3", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("seltenspanisch", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Das kann mal passieren! Aber kontrolliere dich besser! Und wie sieht es mit dem Handy aus? Hast du das unter Kontrolle während der Deutschstunde?", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("handykeinproblem");
    hideElement("handynochproblem");
    hideElement("handyproblem");
  note = note + 5.8;
  note = note/2;
  setScreen("handy");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("handykeinproblem");
  showElement("handynochproblem");
    showElement("handyproblem");
    hideElement ("label9");
  hideElement ("note_3");
  }, 10300);
  setText("note_3", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("oftspanisch", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Du stehst unter Observation, mein Freund! Und wie sieht es mit dem Handy aus? Hast du das unter Kontrolle während der Deutschstunde?", "male", "Deutsch");
  hideElement("handykeinproblem");
    hideElement("handynochproblem");
    hideElement("handyproblem");
  note = note + 5;
  note = note / 2;
  setScreen("handy");
  setTimeout(function() {
    showElement("handykeinproblem");
    showElement("handynochproblem");
    showElement("handyproblem");
    hideElement ("label9");
  hideElement ("note_3");
  }, 10300);
  setText("note_3", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});

onEvent("handykeinproblem", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Sehr gut! Das finde ich toll! Schau mal hier! Das ist deine Zensur für heute!", "male", "Deutsch");
    note = note + 7;
    note = note/2;
    setScreen("finale_note");
    setText("finalnote", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("handynochproblem", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Eventuell kein grosses Problem, aber bitte pass auf, dass du dich kontrollierst! Schau mal hier! Das ist deine Zensur für heute! ", "male", "Deutsch");
  note = note + 4.5;
  note = note/2;
  setScreen("finale_note");
  setText("finalnote", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});
onEvent("handyproblem", "click", function( ) {
  playSound("sound://category_swish/karate_whoosh_14.mp3", false);
  playSpeech("Bitte gib mir dein Handy vor der Stunde! Das wird einen positiven Effekt auf deine Noten haben! Schau mal hier! Das ist deine Zensur für heute!", "male", "Deutsch");
  note = note + 4.5;
  note = note / 2;
  setScreen("finale_note");
  setText("finalnote", Math.round(note * 10) / 10);
});

if ((note <= 5,5)) {
    setText("feedback", warnung);
}

if ((note <= 6)) {
    setText("feedback", neutral);
}

if ((note > 6)) {
    setText("feedback", schulterklopfen);
}

onEvent("nocheinmal", "click", function( ) {
    setScreen("appstart");
});
onEvent("email", "click", function( ) {
  open("https://dschilepodcast.cl/kontakt/");
});
```

Comment: Is that code javascript?

Comment: Dear Scott, I copied this code from the app lab on code.org! I am a total newby! I manage HTML and CSS but these are the first steps with my pupils.

Comment: "I am a total newby! I manage HTML and CSS but these are the first steps with my pupils." - Do you know what language you copied from the app lab?

Comment: code.org claims it is JavaScript, Scott. Basically they provide an editor which you can use in block mode or text mode, in an additional window you can rund the code and see the app working! You can see it here including the code https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/ptv2TZPSBR596v3UorbHClthqBFmH0vNN2y_8YNtwg8.

Comment: "code.org claims it is JavaScript" - If they provided the code and they claim it is Javascript, I would trust that (it does look like Javascript).  I have added the `javascript` tag as that will help you get the attention of folks who know the language more so than `if-statement`.

Comment: Thx a lot, Scott! hopefully someone will come around, my pupils are eager to see it working and also the right solution to the problem! Unfortunately I was not able to solve it with them, but...it has been a lot of fun so far! Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case some newbies will stumble across the same problem

```
if (note>=6.5) {
setText("feedback", schulterklopfen);
  } else if (note>=5.6 && note<=6.4)  {
  setText("feedback", neutral);
  } else setText("feedback", warnung);
```

Also, I had problems with re-intializing the variable 'note' in order to calculate the mark if user chooses to repeat the self-assessment...for this case I calculated the mark ('note') in first step as following:

```
 note = note - note + 7;
```